# What type of wall texture is this? How can I match it?

Tags: drywall, walls, paint, texture, drywall-mud

Looking for what type of wall texture this is, how is it applied (i.e. spray on)? Basement window flooded, I need to match the texturing around the rest of the room.

It looks like a SantaFe variation to me, because it's low profile but I also suspect it's a spray on. I don't have enough experience to know the difference. I could be totally wrong.[image]. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some of it looks like a standard knockdown that was over sprayed, and some of it just looks like poorly done smooth finish. If I was doing it I think I'd shoot for it typical knockdown but put on more mud than normal, so that the plateaus amount to most of the surface area.

Comment: I agree at first I thought knock down, a heavy thick coat that is knocked down with a wide trowl, the second is a orange peal but you can see the original knockdown underneath for a not so good look and Where DIY gets a bad name.